# How do I skew the drop shadow of the top logo to look similar to the bottom logo?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, logo, drop-shadow

How do I skew the drop shadow of the top logo to look similar to the bottom logo
[image]

Comment: Not a job for Photoshop... better suited to Illustrator where you can draw tangents more easily.

Answer (score 1):

There's no skewing here.

Draw extra filled pieces to make the letters look like they are extruded 3D shapes.

An example

[image]

Note: Although you could do this in Photoshop, it's less than ideal for work like this. Better to use a vector image editor for creating logos.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a drop shadow. The letters have got brown inserts which are drawn like the letters have some thickness. Every letter has its own insert which makes it look like it's is extruded to different direction than the others.

The best result (assuming one knows what he wants) can be got by drawing the inserts manually. It's already shown by the others. It can become difficult when the general form of the shape is curved and there are many letters. Anyway, it's possible, but needs some patiency.

Illustrator's legacy 3D effect Extrude&Bevel speeds up things and helps to make it regular. The drawback is that you do not have 100% control. But the result can be good enough. An example:

[image]

In the left there's some text. Every letter has the same grey fill and no stroke.

In the middle the text got Arch Envelope Distortion to make it curved. The arch strength is 25%.

In the right the envelope distortion is expanded and the result is ungrouped to have 4 individual shapes. It's essential to have no strokes nor groups.

In the next strip the letter shapes were selected at the same time and they got the legacy 3D extrusion effect:

[image]

In the left the same effect is applied to all. In the middle the Y axis rotation angles are adjusted manually. They are +12, +6, -6 and -12 degrees.

In the right the shading is changed to "No shading". It's done separately for each letter and it could be done in the same time than the rotations were adjusted. No shading is a must for manual surface coloring.

Manual coloring is possible after expanding the 3D effect. It's done by applying Object > Expand Appearance. It leaves often clipping masks and complex groups. Release clipping masks and ungroup about 5 times to be sure every piece is free. Then you may want to build new groups of items which will get the same color. I didn't make groups because there's only few colors and individual surfaces.

[image]

On the top all shapes are at first colored to dark brown (picked from your image). Then the frontages got orange fill.

In the middle the frontages are all selected and an offset path is made. Negative offset shrinks. The offset paths got brown fill.

In the bottom every item got a stroke. The frontage side shapes got black strokes. The extruded body shapes got the same stroke color than the body itself. It's needed to keep all shape sizes compatible. Every stroke has the same line width. The stroke corners are set to be round to avoid peaky miters.

When you are ready in Illustrator, prepare an empty image in Photoshop with high enough resolution for your purposes. Copy and paste the result to it. You can do it also shape by shape and as paths.

Comment: Question is asking about Photoshop.

Comment: I red it, but wrote the easy receipe for Illustrator. The Photoshop part is inserted recently. If it must vanish, wait a day before you delete it, because the questioner may want to see the easy method. A few downvotes are no harm.

Comment: I did not add the Photoshop part recently. You just didn't read the full text